# formatting a float to string when formatting options are chosen externally (by user)

Tags: python, format, user-defined

I am formatting float values to strings.
The formatting type & accuracy are chosen by the user.

How do I use the chosen formatting parameters during the conversion?

```
formatType = 'e' or 'f' [enum options for user]
formatAccuracy = 0 to 7 [enum options for user]

formatCode = join(formatAccuracy,formatType)

val = 1.23456789

formattedValue = '%%' %val %formatCode
```

but obviously this doesn't work and gets confused with the double %%

Answer (score 0):

had a bit more of a play around and came up with an answer before actually posting this question :)

```
formatCode = formatAccuracy + formatType  (eg. '3e')
formatToString = '%.' + formatCode  (eg. '%3e')
valString = formatToString % value
```

merged into one line...

```
valString = ('%.' + formatAccuracy + formatType) % val
```